# Is "Type arguments constraints can with two restrictions also be used with custom types" a valid sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

[orign](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/602dce88036e2f642e7efefcd150bb7db97979c5/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/ch02.asciidoc#with-custom-parameterized-types).

I think the sentence should be expressed as "Type arguments constraints can also be used with custom types but with two restrictions."

Comment: Although I'm ignorant of the subject matter, I believe that both the original version and your suggested changes are correct. It is a matter of style, rather than correct or incorrect English usage. Personally, I prefer the clarity of your rewrite.

Comment: It's entirely a matter of stylistic choice where you position ***with two restrictions***, and whether you want to clarify the relationship by including ***but***. See written instances of [can with care achieve](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22can+with+care+achieve%22), for example (and so far as I'm concerned, it's also a matter of choice whether to enclose the "optional" *with-clause* in commas.

Answer (score 1):

I think "type arguments constraints" should be "type argument constraints".  Even though there may be several arguments, so there is a logical plural, English doesn't usually allow inflectional endings inside compound words.  If I'm interpreting it right, the structure is "[N [N type argument] constraint]s", which is the plural of a compound noun made up of the two nouns "type argument" and "constraint".  The compound "type argument" is within a compound, so it can't be inflected with "s".  (The archaic "sergeants major" is an exception to the general rule.)

Comment: If "type argument constraints" is intended as a noun phrase, then *argument* must be an adjective, and so not *arguments*. If not, then I can see no way it can be grammatical.

Comment: @TimLymington Few would label the compound _football_ in _football manager_ an adjective.

Comment: _Major_ in _sergeant-major_ is an adjective, not a noun, so it’s not really an exception to the singularity constraint on compounds. @Tim _Argument_ cannot possibly be an adjective in “type argument constraints”. It must be a noun (unless there is some use of _argument_ as a postmodifying adjective that I am unaware of). It’s a nested compound, akin to “tennis shoe constraints”, where _shoe_ is also not an adjective.

Comment: Looking at the original, it seems this is one of just two places on the page where “type argument constraints” has been mistyped (?) as “type arguments constraints”; the other 15 times the term pops up, it is correctly written. The writer (if I’m correctly identifying who the writer is) seems to be French.